# Passing PHP array into external Javascript function as array

Tags: php, javascript

I'm doing something which I need to pass an array from my php to a function on an external javascript. I'm currently doing some test right now which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" onclick="show_error_message('<?php echo $array_sample ?>')" readonly="readonly">
```

and the javascript function is this one:

```
function show_error_message(test) {
alert(test)
}
```

my $array_sample contains data which is `array("1","2","3");`  but the return alert would be Array and whenever I change the `$array_sample` into `$array_sample[0]` when passing the parameters I got a data which is 1 as alert. I wonder how can I pass the whole array on this to be fetched also by an array in javascript. Well as you can see, I intended it to be a popup message for error handling which is why I need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
onclick='show_error_message(<?php echo  json_encode($array_sample) ?>)'
```

or

```
onclick="show_error_message(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($array_sample)) ?>)"
```

Notice the lack of quotes(`'`) around the php code, this way an array literal is passed to `show_error_message` and not a string.

Comment: Oh I see, there's a return value saying function Array() {
    [native code]
} in my alert. using your first edit this one : onclick="show_error_message(<?php echo $array_sample ?>)" but after I use the json_encode part again the alert box won't appear using the function in javascript which is not yet edited. Is that normal?

Comment: @KaHeL I don't see why it won't work, do you get any errors in the console? are you using php version 5.2 or greater?

Comment: Oh, there yes it has an error. SyntaxError: "syntax error
show_error_message([" 
As for PHP I'm using 5.3 64bit wampserver and also I'm using codeigniter as framework. Can that be the cause of problem?

Comment: @KaHeL I just realized that strings will be encoded with `"` which will terminate your `onclick` attribute prematurely,  `onclick="show_error_message(["1","2","3"])"`. You can use single quotes for you attributes or escape the double quotes in the php echo.

Comment: at last! this works! It displays 1,2,3 I think the next step is for me to contain the passed value into a variable array for me to fully control it am I correct? And moreover, thanks for this! I really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @KaHeL `test` is already an array, you can do `alert(test[0])` to see `1` displayed.

Comment: Oh youre right. I thought it was still a formatted string. Works great! Thanks you very much. :)

Answer (score 5):

Encode PHP array to json data using `json_encode()` function.

And in Javascript use `JSON.parse()` to parse the Json string.

Comment: I see, I tried to change my onclick into onclick="show_error_message(<?php echo json_encode($array_sample) ?>)"
and the javascript function in tact but after I clicked my text box the alert won't appear.

Comment: Try something like this:  onclick="show_error_message(<?php echo "'".json_encode($array_sample)."'" ?>)"

Answer (score 4):

The below code shows how to pass php array to javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mufunc(a)
    {
        var temp = new Array();
        temp = a.split('~');
        for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
        {
            alert(temp[i]); 
        }
    }
</script>

<?php
    $a = array('a','b','c');
    $b = implode("~",$a);
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="mufunc('<?php echo $b; ?>')">Click Here</a>
```