# Passing PHP array using json_encode method into external Javascript function gives result as 'undefined'

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I have searched for that, i got some ideas from following site also.
[Passing PHP array into external Javascript function as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116604/passing-php-array-into-external-javascript-function-as-array)
My sample code is below:

```
 <?php $array_sample = array("c1","c2"); $newArray = json_encode($array_sample); ?>
 <INPUT type="button" value="Php Array" onclick="Test(<?php echo $newArray ?>)" />
 <script language="javascript"> function Test(test_arr){    alert(test_arr); }</script>
```

For above code, I am getting `undefined` as `alert message`.
Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the page source look like (after the php parsing is complete)?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `json_encode()`, double-quotes are preserved in the result. So, `json_encode($array_sample)` produces:

```
["c1","c2"]
```

When this is put into your HTML, you have:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Php Array" onclick="Test(["c1","c2"])" />
```

If you can tell, the double-quotes from your json-output break the HTML which break what's passed to the `Test()` method.

To fix this, you could use `htmlentities()` to convert the double-quotes to HTML-values `&quot;`:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Php Array" onclick="Test(<?php echo htmlentities($newArray) ?>)" />
```

**EDIT** (`htmlentities()` vs. `addslashes()`)
It appears that using `addslashes()` actually won't work because an escaped double-quote in an attribute, such as `onclick="Test(\"value\")"` is invalid. However, an html-entity version such as `onclick="Test(&quot;value&quot;)"` works.

Because of this, I have changed my original answer from "use `addslashes()`" to "use `htmlentities()`").

Comment: Thanks for reply to all but still i am getting 'undefined' in alert. here is page source: <script language="javascript"> function Test(arr) { alert(arr); } /script> <html> <body> <INPUT type="button" value="Php Array" onclick="Test()" /> </body> </html> Array ( [0] => c1 [1] => c2 )

Comment: @Alpa The sample code in your comment hints that you're using `print_r($array_sample);`, not `echo $newArray;`. Make sure you're using `echo` and not `print_r()` *and* `$newArray` (which is your json-encoded string) and not `$array_sample`, which is still a PHP-array.

Comment: Yes, $array_sample is my php-array, $newArray is my json-encoded array and that i m passing to javascript function using htmlentities($newArray). yes, i was using print_r() for printing array. if i use echo, the page view source will be like: <script language="javascript"> function Test(arr) { alert(arr); } /script> <html> <body> <INPUT type="button" value="Php Array" onclick="Test()" /> </body> </html> Array <br/>[&quot;c1&quot;,&quot;c2&quot;]. why function Test() is empty eventhough i am passing array to it?

Comment: @Alpa I'm sorry, but I can't replicate your issue. If I copy+paste your code *exactly*, it outputs the json into the correct place. If I add `htmlentities()` into your code exactly where I showed to place it, it outputs the json into the correct place. What this says to me is that *you* aren't using the code you put into this question - so I'm kind of in the dark. I *know* you're not using the code from your question as, in your question, `<script>` comes after`<INPUT` - but your new output it's reversed. Please update with your exact code and I can help more =]

Comment: Now i got it. I am getting an array now. a json array that i have passed from php code to javascript function, that json array values i am getting in javascript. i have print it in javascript like alert(arr); so it shows like ["c1","c2","c3"], eventhough i have used htmlentities function. if i try to print only first value in alert like alert(arr[0]); it doesn't. actually in javascript i want to proced on each arry element separately. how can i do that?